# Az query to list all subscriptions, resource groups and resources in it

Tags: bash, azure, powershell

I am trying to iterate over all azure subscriptions, resource groups and resources

Comment: Can you be more specific, what's the end goal? Are you trying to get a list of all resources in your environment? What have you already tried/explored but does not work for you? There are different ways to achieve this depending on your needs.

Comment: @KedMardemootoo i am trying to list all of the resources in my env consisting of many subscriptions. my end goal is to get the result in a csv format and feed it to a dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way of doing it would be to use the [Azure Resource Graph Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/overview). I find it to be very powerful, flexible and hassle-free for querying anything about Azure. I'd suggest to give it a try if you're often going to be working with Azure inventory - it's also very user-friendly and uses KQL as query language. You can easily filter out the results as you need.

Here's how you would query all resources across all of your subscriptions:

1. Make sure the scope is your entire tenant
2. Type the following query:

```
resources
```

3. Run the query
4. Download as CSV

Here's how this would look like below:

[image]

Comment: This helps..thank you so much!!

Comment: Sure, no problem! Please mark as answer or upvote if you think this answered or helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below **PowerShell script** to pull the list of all subscriptions & their resource groups & resources in it.

```
Connect-AzAccount
$subs=Get-AzSubscription
foreach($sub in $subs){

  Set-AzContext -Subscription $sub.id -Force
  $resourcegroups= Get-AzResourceGroup
  Write-Host "Currently connected  to subscription"$sub.id -ForegroundColor red -BackgroundColor white

  foreach($rg in $resourcegroups){

    Write-Host "Current resourcegroup"$rg.ResourceGroupName -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
    Write-Host "Here are list of resources present in this resource group:" -ForegroundColor Cyan 
    $resource=Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName
    Write-Output $resource.ResourceName
    

  }
}
```

**Here is the sample Output for reference:**

[image]

Comment: @S_K, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you